# JS nested promises in for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have something like:

```js
let promises = [];
fetch("list.of.names").then(names => {

for n of names {
  promises.push(fetch("names/"+n));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(all => {
  for item of all {
    //item and name `n` are needed:
    element.innerText += n + ": " item.info;
  }
})

})
```

And the thing is I need both in the end, but obviously n is just the last value, because the for loop already finished. Any idea how I can do that nicely? Is there a way to append elements to a promise?

Comment: Check out [ParentNode#append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

Comment: @Thomas thanks, u right.. I simplified my question and actually do a whole lot more DOM manipulation.. but that's not the point of the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can make `fetch(name)` resolve into something like `[result, name]`:

```
fetch("list.of.names").then(names => {
    let promises = [];

    for (let name of names) {
        promises.push(
            fetch("names/" + name).then(item => [item, name])
        );
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);

}).then(all => {
    for (let [item, name] of all) {
        // do stuff
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an improvement (imo.) of [@basickarl's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66797580/6567275)

```
(async() => {
  // this needs to be done first:
  const names = await fetch('list.of.names');
  
  // this part, we'd like to happen in paralell:
  const promises = names.map(async(name) => [name, await fetch(`names/${name}`)]);
  // there are no guarantees that the requests will resolve in sequence; nor do we care.
  
  // but this, we'd want to be executed in sequence:
  for await (const [name, item] of promises) {
    element.innerText += name + ': ' + item.info;
  }
})();
```

Comment: I like how you split up modelling the data then using it. I would of done a promise.all however on the first part instead of the for await.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(async () => {
    const names = await fetch('list.of.names');
    const namesAndItemsPromises = names.map(async (name) => {
        const item = await fetch(`names/${name}`);
        element.innerText += name + ': ' + item.info;
        return [name, item];
    });
    const namesAndItems = Promise.all(namesAndItemsPromises);
})();
```

My advice would be to try and get away from "then" as much as possible, it causes so much confusion.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66798003/6567275), it's based on your code.